# Search a authors/books data module by lang using JavaScript .map() and .filter()

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to search the following data module by language `books.lang` using `.map()` and `.filter()`. If there's no language defined, the function returns all authors with relative books. If a language is requested, the function returns only the authors who have books translated in this language.

The data module is the following:

```
// data.js
const authors = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Author 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Author 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Author 3"
  }
];

const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    authorId: 1,
    lang: "IT",
    title: "Title 1",
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    authorId: 1,
    lang: "EN",
    title: "Title 2",
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    authorId: 2,
    lang: "IT",
    title: "Title 1",
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    authorId: 2,
    lang: "FR",
    title: "Title 2",
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    authorId: 3,
    lang: "IT",
    title: "Title 1",
    date: "2018-07-07"
  }
];

module.exports = { authors, books };
```

A common solution works using the classic for loop. But I can't find the right solution using only `.map()` and `.filter()` and eventualy chaining them, it doesn't group books by author. For each author, I create a `books` property to group the relative books.

The classic working solution is the following:

```
const lang = "IT";

filtered_books = books.filter( book => lang !== null ? book.lang == lang : book.lang !== '' ); 

for (let i in authors) {
    authors[i].books = filtered_books.filter( book => book.authorId == authors.id);
}
```

Here is where I'm stuck with my `.map()` and `.filter()` solution:

```
const lang = "IT";

const selectedAuthors = books.filter( book => lang !== null ? book.lang == lang : book.lang !== '' )
                             .map( book => { 
                                 return authors.filter( author => { 
                                     if(author.id == book.authorId) return author.books = book; // Should I push something here?
                             });
                         });
```

With or without the `lang` parameter, it doesn't group the resulting books by author.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure that `.map()` is appropriate. The whole point of `.map()` is to produce an array *the same size* as an original array; a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Also can't you just make one `.filter()` call and check *both* the language and author?

Comment: Thanks Pointy for help.

Comment: I would say that you shouldn't associate authors and books using `ids` but references (i.e. `book.author` instead of `book.authorId`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like a two-stage pass - 1) combine the authors with their books, and 2) filter out those authors who have books in the specified language.

```js
const authors = [{"id":1,"name":"Author 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Author 2"},{"id":3,"name":"Author 3"}];
const books = [{"id":1,"authorId":1,"lang":"IT","title":"Title 1","date":"2018-06-07"},{"id":2,"authorId":1,"lang":"EN","title":"Title 2","date":"2018-06-07"},{"id":3,"authorId":2,"lang":"IT","title":"Title 1","date":"2018-06-07"},{"id":4,"authorId":2,"lang":"FR","title":"Title 2","date":"2018-06-07"},{"id":5,"authorId":3,"lang":"IT","title":"Title 1","date":"2018-07-07"}];

function findBooks(authors, books, lng) {

  // map over the books and get their books
  const combined = authors.map(author => {
    const filteredBooks = lng
      ? books.filter(book => book.authorId === author.id && book.lang === lng)
      : books.filter(book => book.authorId === author.id)
    return { ...author, books: filteredBooks };
  });

  // if a language has been specified, return only those authors who have books
  // in that language
  return lng ? combined.filter(author => author.books.some(book => book.lang === lng)) : combined;
}

const authorBooks = findBooks(authors, books);
console.log(authorBooks);

const authorBooksLng = findBooks(authors, books, 'EN');
console.log(authorBooksLng);
```

Comment: I love that: `return { ...author, books: filteredBooks }`, nice lesson on logic and array operators and methods. Thanks Andy

Comment: Sorry Andy, your script helped me a lot, it returns the authors who have a book translated in the requested language but also the books of the same author in another language. I would like to only get the book in the requested language.

Comment: @Ed-le-mince, easily fixed. Take a look at the updated answer